# Restcomm - configuring incoming DID with Nexmo

Tags: sip, vonage, mobicents, restcomm

We are trying to create a testing environment with Restcomm and a Nexmo DID incoming number. We followed [this tutorial](http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-connecting-to-external-did-providers/).
Although we are not sure about step 3, so we leave that aside.

When we try sendig calls from Nexmo, Restcomm answers with a **404 Not Found**. As you can see in the caputre below, Nexmo seems to send the INVITE to the configured uri, but in the TO field it sends the orignial numbrer with sip.local as domain. We provisioned both sip numbers in Restcomm, but we are getting 404 Not found nonetheless .

```
root@xxxxxxxxxx restcomm]# tcpdump -i eth0 -A port 5060 or port 5080
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
12:41:52.770616 IP sip.nexmo.com.sip > xxxxxxxxxx: SIP, length: 1434
E....F..7.($.$..............INVITE sip:1234@restcommuri:5080 SIP/2.0
Record-Route: <sip:174.36.197.206;r2=on;lr=on;ftag=7f73898f1e08-0-13c4-6009-1d0230-987ae6e-1d0230>
Record-Route: <sip:10.24.134.35;r2=on;lr=on;ftag=7f73898f1e08-0-13c4-6009-1d0230-987ae6e-1d0230>
From: <sip:16617480240@10.24.134.38:5060>;tag=7f73898f1e08-0-13c4-6009-1d0230-987ae6e-1d0230
To: <sip:12604079432@sip.local>
Call-ID: 1432658509204-7f7345112920-165098f0-00aad521@10.24.134.38
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 174.36.197.206;branch=z9hG4bK996f.cd8208f2948af59b669b042318445a43.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.24.134.38:5060;received=10.24.134.38;rport=5060;branch=z9hG4bK-1d0230-71508e1b-7ec52f5f-7f7389136468
P-Preferred-Identity: tel:16617480240
Max-Forwards: 69
User-Agent: VCS13.0.9.112.76766
Contact: <sip:16617480240@10.24.134.38:5060;alias=10.24.134.38~5060~1>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 527

v=0
o=- 1 1 IN IP4 174.37.226.130
s=voxeo.13.0.9.112.76766
c=IN IP4 174.37.226.130
t=0 0
m=audio 11220 RTP/AVP 18 0 8 101 97 9 3 102 103 104 116
a=rtpmap:18 G729/8000
a=fmtp:18 annexb=no
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=rtpmap:97 G726-32/8000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
a=rtpmap:102 AMR-WB/16000
a=rtpmap:103 AMR/8000
a=rtpmap:104 iSAC/16000
a=rtpmap:116 SPEEX/16000
a=ptime:20
a=oldmediaip:10.24.134.38
a=oldmediaip:10.24.134.38

12:41:52.786439 IP xxxxxxxxxxxx > sip.nexmo.com.sip: SIP, length: 613
E.....@.@........$.......m:LSIP/2.0 404 Not found
To: <sip:12604079432@sip.local>;tag=67270726_2a5bf6d7_57a5b08a_b61fcf9c-ec05-468a-ae6c-f0c6cbf0d972
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 174.36.197.206;branch=z9hG4bK996f.cd8208f2948af59b669b042318445a43.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.24.134.38:5060;received=10.24.134.38;rport=5060;branch=z9hG4bK-1d0230-71508e1b-7ec52f5f-7f7389136468
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Call-ID: 1432658509204-7f7345112920-165098f0-00aad521@10.24.134.38
From: <sip:16617480240@10.24.134.38:5060>;tag=7f73898f1e08-0-13c4-6009-1d0230-987ae6e-1d0230
Server: TelScale Sip Servlets 7.0.2-SNAPSHOT
Contact: <sip:54.83.196.238:5060>
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that you are are making a call to the port 5060.

Could you try call the number using SIP sip:your_number@IP:5080

Restcomm listens on port 5080 by default.

By the way, is this instance running on Amazon Cloud?

Comment: The call is being made to port 5080, the capture filter included 5060 just in case. I relplaced the destination ip and port with XX but it was 5080 port guaranteed.
Yes this is running on Amazon Cloud